# Why is the Tryparse not working and instantly throwing the catch?

Tags: c#, tryparse

The result won't go-to my Result textbox, and as soon as I type anything into number one, it instantly gives me the "Number 2 is invalid" catch. I'm very new and don't understand why it won't work.

```
namespace ShippingCalculator_BradleyH
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        double total;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Number1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //assigning variables
            double num1;
            double num2;
            double result;

            //making sure numbers 1 and 2 are numbers.
            if (double.TryParse(Number1.Text, out num1))
            {
                if (double.TryParse(Number2.Text, out num2))
                {
                    result = num1 * num2;
                    Result.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Number 2 is invalid.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number 1 is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume both text  boxes are initially empty. As soon as you enter something in `Number1`, this code will run, and `Number2` will be empty. An empty string is an invalid `double`, thus `TryParse` will return `false`.

Here's what I'd suggest:

- First, pull this logic out into a separate function. Call it `UpdateResult` or something similar.
- Call this function from both `Number1_TextChanged` and `Number2_TextChanged`
- In `UpdateResult`, apply the follow logic:

  - If either `Number1.Text` or `Number2.Text` are empty strings, then set `Result.Text` to an empty string.
  - Otherwise, perform your existing logic.

Comment: I found my problem, I didn't realize all of the code I put was under the Number1.Textbox and not my calculate button. But thank you Jonathon!